# Exception during createing exe file

Tags: java, exe, launch4j, runnable-jar

Im trying to convert my runnable jar into .exe file but i get this Exception in Launch4j program:

```
Executing: C:\Users\szymo\Desktop\SwordAndOgrs.exe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:515)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:417)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:416)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 13 more
```

While im running code from Eclipse it works perfect. I already add javaFx SDK to buildPath.

Comment: Didn you include JavaFX to your executable?? JavaFX since JAVA SDK {{some version}} does not have JavaFX bundled.

Comment: How to include javaFX to my executable? Is this some options in Launch4j?